# LaTeX: How to set the pdf dpi when using images

Tags: image, latex, jpeg, pdflatex, dpi

I'm writing my thesis in LaTeX and I have troubles with the image imports.

I want to get my thesis as a PDF, which imports some JPEG images of charts and other things.  I'd like to have a higher resolution; by default MikTeX settings I have my image resized to a crappy resolution.

I'm using MikTeX, Adobe Reader 9.4, Win7 32.

How can I raise the resolution of the PDF produced from my LaTeX sources?

Is there any other way to insert a pick without losing resolution?

I know about vectorial formats, but I have only BMP or JPG to insert in my thesis.

A part of the code is this: (the first 2 rows doesn't work =/)

```
\pdfpxdimen=2in    
\divide\pdfpxdimen by 300

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\include{Frontespizio}

\newpage

\include{Ringraziamenti}

\tableofcontents 

\newpage

\include{Introduzione}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\scriptsize \leftmark} \lfoot{}

\cfoot{\thepage} \rfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\include{Capitolo1}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

And the Image calling is:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]    
    \centering    
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{UseCase.png}    
    \label{fig: Use Cases}    
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Please show an example image and the import command.  Importing an image usually has no effect on its resolution (pixel numbers), so the DPI are only dependent on the size at which it is displayed.

Comment: FYI: There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Added the code of the call and a tentative for change the dpi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i suggest you to use .png images.

If you still want to change dpi you may insert this code on .tex preamble:

\pdfpxdimen=1in

\divide\pdfpxdimen by 96

(for 96dpi)

Comment: I've tried to wrote down the 2 rows you've written, but it doesn't work.. I tried also changing parameters..